# Function returns wrong value while step-by-step debugging inside the function seems to be ok

Tags: c++

The problem is described in the title.

I have two functions. In the first I get file name (variable `text`), but the function does not return expected value. After returning the value `text`, it becomes an abrakadabra. But in the second function variable `text` is returned correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
char* GetCurrentClipboardData(...)
{
    char* text;
    wchar_t file[MAX_PATH];

    if( OpenClipboard(NULL) )
    {   
        HGLOBAL hFile = (HGLOBAL)GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP);
        if (hFile)
        {
            HDROP hDrop = (HDROP)GlobalLock(hFile);
            DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0, file, MAX_PATH);
            _bstr_t b(file);
            text = b;
            if (text != Text)
            {
                SaveDataToFile (file_path, current_time, text);
                char* copy = ReadFile(shadowcopy_path);
                if (copy == "1")
                    MakeFileShadowCopy(file, shadowcopies);
            }
            GlobalUnlock(hFile);
        }

        HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
        if (hBitmap)
        {
            text = "Изображение";
            if (text != Text)
            {
                SaveDataToFile (image_path, current_time, text);
                char* copy = ReadFile(shadowcopy_path);
                if (copy == "1")
                    MakeImageShadowCopy(hBitmap, shadowcopies, current_date, current_time);
            }
            GlobalUnlock(hBitmap);
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: `text = b;` points into the `_bstr_t` object, making it a dangling pointer once the `_bstr_t` object is destroyed. You will need to change your code to return some string object that manages its own memory (either `_bstr_t` or something else)

Answer (score 2):

The function returns a pointer `text` which is freed once the function returns, hence it is undefined behavior. You can use malloc to allocate memory for it on the heap but you also need to free it.

```
char* text;
text = (char*)malloc(text_size * sizeof(char));
```

or for C++,

```
char* text = new char[text_size];
```

where `text_size` is the size of your string.

Comment: Any reason for using malloc here instead of new?

Comment: No,  Missed the c++ tag.

Comment: Any reason you are not using `std::string`

Comment: because the op used `char*`

Comment: @Ed Heal I have substituted char* to std::string and everything works now! Thanks a lot for the great advice.